# Sorting by a date in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, date

Silly question, but I cannot find an answer to this anywhere, and any attempts I have made to solve it myself have not yielded fruit so far.

Here's the code. I create an array. Then in a loop, I make several objects and insert these into the array. Then I try to sort based on the attribute 'date'. Then I print to test. It all works, but for the sort :

```
<% @subject.list_people.each do |people| %>
    <% people.people_family.each do |family| %>
      <% family.find_friends.each do |friends| %>

       myObj = {}

        <% myObj['name1'] = people['name'].first %>
        <% myObj['name2'] = family['name'].first %>
        <% myObj['date'] = friends['date'].first %>

        <% myArray << myObj %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %> 
  <% myArray = myArray.sort_by! { |obj| obj['date'] } %> //Sort the list based on field date

<% myArray.each do |myObj| %>
  <i><%= myObj['date'] %></i>
<% end %>
```

I want to have the most recently dated objects be printed first. Whatever I change, however,does not edit the order that my data is printed. How can I order on this date field ?

Comment: Usually, in Ruby functions an ! at the end means that you want to apply the result to the variable, rather then just return it. You can omit the "myArray = " part. Also, this sort of functionality is generally not something you want to implement in the view (although the format generated is very specific to the view). I would suggest you make this a function of the Subject-class, that returns the resulting array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need to start from most recently objects, you need to reverce your array:

```
myArray = myArray.sort_by { |obj| obj['date'] }.reverse
```

In Ruby more recent date is greater then less recent:

```
Date.today > Date.today - 2
=> true
```

Comment: @llya There are times when I really, really love this message board. I can't believe it was that simple. I spent about an hour troubleshooting this, and this one little method call fixed it !!! Thank you!